# Correct way to run methods off the UI thread?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

I'm running a method asynchronously on the main page in the OnNavigateTo() method.

First of all is it correct to do it this way?

Second is there an alternative way to run the method without calling it from OnNavigateTo()?

For example

```
 protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            GeoLocate.ConsentPrompt();

            await RunTasks();
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried doing Task.Run(() => RunTasks())?

Comment: @igrali I found out the stuttering of the UI on launch was caused by the panorama background image not the way I was calling the methods

Comment: Prior to .Net 4.0, it would've require you to use `BackgroundWorker`, or use async methods (`BeginXXX`, `EndXXX`).  In .Net 4.0, and above, the TPL (Tasks parallel library) provides use with all the tool you need (Tasks, as @igrali suggested).